# That would be me vs That's me

Tags: meaning, differences

Mike : You are Lebron. You are Brad. And you must be Tim.
Tim : That would be me. Nice to meet you.

Why does Tim use "That would be me" instead of "That's me." ?

What is the difference between "That would be me" and "That's me"?

Answer (score 2):

"That's me" is much more informal as contractions are. "That would be me" is more formal, or mock-formal which is what I suspect is happening here. The latter is used for humorous effect.